# FrameLayout content order

Tags: android, xml

I'm learning Android and I was trying out FrameLayout containing ImageViews, I tried to do a little app that switchs between two images when you click on them the code is the following:

My xml looks like this:

>

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Hola" >

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/segunda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="metodosegunda"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img1" />

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/primera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="metodoprimera"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And my main program:

```
public class Hola extends Activity {
ImageView primera;
ImageView segunda;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.teta_layout);
    primera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.primera); 
    segunda = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.segunda); 

}


public void metodoprimera (View view){ 
    primera.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    segunda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


} 

public void metodosegunda (View view){ 

    segunda.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    primera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
}
```

This program should show an image and as soon as you click on it it should hide that image and show the other and so on.

The thing is that this won't work , but as soon as I switch the imageview order in the xml, it works, and i don't really understand why it should not work this way.

Thank you guys in advance

Comment: Please feel free to explain, completely and precisely, what "this won't work" means.

Comment: This program should show an image and as soon as you click on it it should hide that image and show the other and so on. "This won't work" means that the program won't do anything when you click on the image

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

to the XML for one of the ImageView's.

Comment: @SirukViktor Yes, but when your application starts, you only want one visible. Then when you click on it, you hide it and make the other visible.

Comment: I tried that, and even set the other imageview visible , it will change which one is showing but still if you click on the image it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to go more explicit with the explanation, here is the thing:

If I have the XML like this it will show the images (depending on visibility) but the oClick thing will not work:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Hola" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/segunda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="metodosegunda"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/primera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="metodoprimera"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:visibility="visible" />        

</FrameLayout>
```

If I swap the ImageView's order in the XML It will work perfectly:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Hola" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/primera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="metodoprimera"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/segunda"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="metodosegunda"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:visibility="gone" />     

</FrameLayout>
```

It's not about the visibility of each Imageview since it does not matter what value I put on them It won't work the first way but i will work the second way.

Seems like a weird issue since the oder of the imageviews should not matter if you set them visible or gone ...